# Qual é a diferença entre “dá” e “da”?

Tags: ortografia, crase

Qual é a diferença entre as  palavras *dá* e *da*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **da** – Preposição `de` + Artigo `a`.
>
> **dá** – Verbo `dar` conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular `ele/ela dá`.

Uso:

> O pirulito é **da** Talita.

O sentido da frase é que o pirulito **pertence** a Talita.

> Talita **dá** pirulito a seus primos.

O sentido da frase é que Talita **distribui** pirulito a seus primos.

Comment: Só pra complementar. `da` = preposição `de` + artigo `a`.